# Export Multiple named PDF's from MS Access - Data fields not appearing in exported PDF's

Tags: ms-access

First of all.. Many thanks to COmputerVersteher and BankBuilder!!

The export works fine but these data fields do not appear in the export which is needed:

FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, DEGREE_TYPE, SCHOOL, HONORS, TITLE, GRADUATION_DATE

Below is the code:

Code:

```
Private Sub Export_Diploma_letters_Click()
' change NewButton to the name of your new button for printing all students
    Dim filename As String
    Dim filepath As String
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    'Dim db As Object
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    ' change the name of the table to match your student table           vvvvvvvv
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT STUDENT_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, DEGREE_TYPE, SCHOOL, HONORS, TITLE, GRADUATION_DATE FROM Humanities", dbOpenSnapshot)

    Do Until rs.EOF
        ' reference the desired field names in the current row
        filename = rs("LAST_NAME") & "," & " " & rs("FIRST_NAME") & "," & " " & rs("STUDENT_ID")
        filepath = "C:\Users\ddennis1\Desktop\" & filename & ".pdf"
        DoCmd.OpenReport "Humanities_MiniDips", acViewPreview, , "[Student_ID]" = rs("STUDENT_ID")
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Humanities_MiniDips", acFormatPDF, filepath
        DoCmd.Close acReport, "Humanities_MiniDips", acSaveNo
        ' This line logs the export for each student, this will help you with
        ' troubleshooting for specific students if necessary. The log can be found
        ' by pressing Ctrl + G while in the VBA editor in Access.
        Debug.Print "PDF for " & rs("FIRST_NAME") & " " & rs("LAST_NAME") & " exported"
        ' move to the next record, CRITICAL or else you will loop forever
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    ' indicate that export is finished
    MsgBox "Graduates exported", vbInformation, "Save confirmed"

End Sub
```

Any ideas and many thanks.

Comment: Are they showing in report preview in Access? What is report RecordSource?

Comment: They are showing up in report preview in Access. Report RecordSource is a query called Humanities. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Hello June 7, what did you edit to the coding? I cannot see your edits. Thank you.

Comment: Edited just to correctly format code. Edit question to show query SQL. Are you using lookup fields in tables? Do ID values show instead of descriptive text?

Comment: I am using a query called "HUMANITIES" which is the data source and contains the "STUDENT_ID" The exported PDF does not need to show the "STUDENT_ID" . The report is Called "HUMANITIES_MINIDIPS" I hope this info helps. Thank you.

Comment: Does not answer questions.